# Office task pane window.open() -> browser popup window closes when document closes

Tags: javascript, ms-office, customtaskpane

We have a custom Office task pane and when the user clicks a certain button in the pane, it launches a popup window via javascript window.open(). This all works fine, however when the document is closed, the browser popup window also closes causing users to potentially lose work. Is there a way to allow this window to stay open when the document closes?

Here's the javascript window open command I'm using:

```
var win = window.open(hyperLink, '', 'left=15,top=15,width=' + (screen.availWidth * 0.95) + ',height=' + (screen.availHeight * 0.85) + ',scrollbars=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,status=1,titlebar=1');
```

Comment: Just to update, we have not found a solution to this problem. Working on a work-around of popping up an intermediary window that opens the target window and then closes itself. This seems to allow the target window to stay open when the office document closes.